# A/B Test - User-level CTR

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, experiment-design

I was hoping to get thoughts on my logic/thought process here

I'm confused when it comes to running an A/B test on CTR. Experiments are typically allocated on a user-level, while CTR is typically an impression level metric (i.e. # of clicks / # of impressions)

How do we reconcile this?

My thoughts...

Aggregate data on a user-level, meaning each row is now a user_id with columns impressions, clicks, and ctr.

We can then calculate some weighted mean of ctr and weighted variance/stdev of ctr across users.

Does this make sense? Am i overcomplicating things? Would love some thoughts here

Comment: Why not record a binary variable for if the user clicked within some time frame after initial exposure (e.g 24 hours)

Comment: can you elaborate @DemetriPananos? so youre saying we can aggregate our data in a way where every row is a user, and we indicate 1 or 0 if they clicked within X hours. what would we do from there? does this ignore the fact that users might be "power" users aka some users will have many impressions and that those impressions are correlated with each other? im honestly not sure, just trying to understand the problem. how would i use your example to calculate sample size?

Comment: *"Aggregate data on a user-level, meaning each row is now a user_id with columns impressions, clicks, and ctr"* This makes a lot of sense. What are you doing now instead?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to eschew sessions and instead use a boolean value for if the user clicked on your CTA/button/whatever within some specified time range from their initial exposure.

For example, You could measure if users click on the CTA within 24 hours of their initial exposure.  Any click, would yield a 1 in their row.  No click in 24 hours would yield a 0.  This would yield one row per user, with a treatment status indicator and and indicator for if the outcome was observed within the desired time.  Note that "power users" can not influence this metric like they can when analyzing session level outcomes; the outcome for each user is either a 0 or a 1.  There are no outliers in this respect.

The problem is then the comparison of success rates for two binomial random variables and you can use a z test of proportions, or a logistic regression, or whatever you want.  Appropriate techniques for statistical power can be taken from there depending on which analysis you intend to perform.

What you lose in this approach is the interpretation.  If CTR is defined as # clicks per # impressions then we are analyzing something different (namely, the risk of observing the outcome within time t, which is of course different). Maybe that doesn't matter, maybe it does, but it is important to know you are answering a slightly different question.